# Code efficiency using VectorGrid in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have about 7 000 polygons in a GeoJSON file using VectorGrid, all is fine using one layer but I need to split this layer into 10 LayerGroups (10 regions with their own polygons). How can this be done without rewriting the code 10 times? That seems to be lots of waste, there must be a smarter way and I can't figure it out. This is the code Im testing with, the highlight has to be working with all 11 layers...

```
var all_regions = new L.layerGroup();
var region_1 = new L.layerGroup();
var region_2 = new L.layerGroup();
var region_3 = new L.layerGroup();
/* snip */
var region_10 = new L.layerGroup();

var highlight_polygon;
var clearHighlight = function () {
  if (highlight_polygon) {
    vectorGrid.resetFeatureStyle(highlight_polygon);
  }
  highlight_polygon = null;
};

var vectorTileOptions_allRegions = {
  rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
  maxNativeZoom: 13,
  zIndex: 6,
  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
    sliced: {
      weight: 2,
      color: "gray",
      opacity: 1,
      fill: false,
      //fillColor: 'white',
      //stroke: true,
      fillOpacity: 0,
    },
  },
  interactive: true,
  getFeatureId: function (f) {
    return f.properties.id;
  },
};

var vectorTileOptions_region_1 = {
  rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
  maxNativeZoom: 13,
  zIndex: 6,
  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
    sliced: function (properties, zoom) {
      var region = properties.region;
      if (region === "region one") {
        return {
          weight: 2,
          color: "gray",
          opacity: 1,
          fill: false,
          //fillColor: 'white',
          //stroke: true,
          fillOpacity: 0,
        };
      } else {
        return {
          weight: 0,
          opacity: 0,
          fill: false,
          stroke: false,
          fillOpacity: 0,
          interactive: false,
        };
      }
    },
  },
  interactive: true,
  getFeatureId: function (f) {
    return f.properties.id;
  },
};

// Next vectorTileOptions until all 11 of them....

$.getJSON("/data/regions.geojson", function (json) {
  //Not sure this is the correct way doing it...

  var vectorGrid = L.vectorGrid
    .slicer(json, vectorTileOptions_allRegions, vectorTileOptions_region_1)

    .on("click", function (e) {
      var properties = e.layer.properties;
      L.popup()
        .setContent(
          "<b>Name</b>: " +
            properties.region_name +
            "<br><b>Date</b>: " +
            "<i>" +
            properties.date +
            "</i>"
        )
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .openOn(map);
      clearHighlight();
      highlight_polygon = e.layer.properties.id;

      vectorGrid.setFeatureStyle(highlight_polygon, {
        weight: 3,
        color: "gray",
        opacity: 1,
        fillColor: "#ff9999",
        fill: true,
        radius: 6,
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
      });
      L.DomEvent.stop(e);
    });

  var clearHighlight = function () {
    if (highlight_polygon) {
      vectorGrid.resetFeatureStyle(highlight_polygon);
    }
    highlight_polygon = null;

    map.on("popupclose", clearHighlight);
  };
  //This will not work....
  vectorGrid.addTo(all_regions);
  vectorGrid.addTo(region_1);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do something like...

```
var regions = []; // An array that will hold instances of VectorGrid

var vectorGridOptions = {
  rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
  maxNativeZoom: 13,
  zIndex: 6,
  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
    sliced: {}, // Empty, because it shall be overwritten later.
  },
};

var defaultStyle = {
  stroke: true,
  weight: 2,
};

var regionStyles = [];

regionStyles[0] = {
  weight: 2,
  color: "gray",
};
regionStyles[1] = {
  weight: 1,
  color: "red",
};
/* ...etc, up to regionStyles[9] */

fetch("/data/regions.geojson")
  .then(function (response) { return response.json(); })
  .then(function (json) {
      
    // For each number between 0 and 9...
    for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        
      // Assuming that the GeoJSON data holds a FeatureCollection,
      // create a copy of said GeoJSON FeatureCollection, but holding only
      // the wanted features.
      // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
      var filteredGeoJSON = {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: json.features.filter(function (feature) {
          // This assumes that each Feature has a "regionID" property with a
          // numeric value between 0 and 9.
          return feature.properties.regionID === i;
        }),
      };

      // Build up the options for the i-th VectorGrid by merging stuff together.
      // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign
      var fullRegionStyle = Object.assign({}, defaultStyle, regionStyles[i]);

      // Overwrite some stuff in vectorGridOptions. Note that this changes the value of
      // a piece of vectorGridOptions at each pass of the loop.
      vectorGridOptions.vectorTileLayerStyles.sliced = fullRegionStyle;

      regions[i] = L.vectorGrid.slicer(filteredGeoJSON, vectorTileOptions);
      regions[i].addTo(map);
    }
  });
```

The key points here are:

- Use a loop to iterate from 1 through 10
- Keep things in numbered arrays instead of similarly-named variables
- Filter the `FeatureCollection`, so each VectorGrid works with less data. Drawing invisible polygons/polylines would take as much computing time as drawing visible ones.
- Refactor as much as possible, then build up concrete data structures (`Object.assign`, clone objects if needed)